# Tornado Post Method Not Found

Tags: tornado

I'm trying to post a form in Tornado web server but whenever I click submit the following error generates

`405 Method Not Allowed`

Here is the form

```
<form method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I've tried changing the "get" method on the main Request Handler to "post" but it doesn't work. The only method that works is GET,

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler):
    """
    Main request handler for the root path and for chat rooms.
    """

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self, room=None):
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will have to supply an endpoint to your form (`<form method="post" action="/whatever">`) and then create that endpoint in your request handler (`def post(self):`). Otherwise either the form won't speak to the handler or the server will not listen.

Comment: Which handler do you want to use for your POST request?


    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/room/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$", MainHandler),
    (r"/login", LoginHandler),
    (r"/logout", LogoutHandler),
    (r"/socket", ChatSocketHandler),
    (r"/socket/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$", ChatSocketHandler),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After that long window of chat I've figured that the best method for you specifically is to transfer the data through cookies.

Here's a tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

An alternative resource is to breakdown your data into multiple parts.

One approach would be to make a request to an end point that allocates you a unique ID. Then send a series of requests in the form: `?id=XXX&page=1&data=...` before closing it with `?id=XXX&total_pages=27` at which point you assemble the different pieces on the server.

Answer (score 3):

The only method that works is `GET` because the only method you've defined on your handler subclass is `get()`. To handle `POST`, define a `post()` method instead of (or in addition to) `get()`.

Comment: Thanks Ben, and how exactly do I define post method?

Comment: `def post(self, room=None):` (probably with the asynchronous decorator), just like you're doing with `get`

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the right handler? Your form submits to demo_form.asp which isn't in the complete code you posted.

Comment: I forgot to edit out the demo_form.asp. Otherwise, everything else is fine with the form, and I'm certainly hitting the right handler.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the sample project and ran it myself. I think I've made some progress.

First, the original MainHandler is not capable of handling POST request. According to the code, it handles request like `/room/1`, `/room/2`.

Second, I'm thinking that you are trying to mimic the login form. However the login form is using GET method and `/login` as endpoint:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/login" method="get">
```

I guess that you also put your form in index.html, whose URL is actually `/login`(if not logged in) or `/room/X`(logged in). So you are probably hitting the LoginHandler.

Third, when I add a post method in MainHandler and send a POST request to `/room/1`, **it's actually working** and triggers a 500 Internal Error.

I use curl to test several cases. If you try to send a POST request to MainHandler on `/`, it doesn't even respond! Because, as mentioned before, get is defined as get(self, room=None). It only accepts `/room/X`.

If you try it on `/room` or `/login`, the response would be `405 Method Not Allowed`.

If you want POST available for `/login`, the simplest way is to add POST in LoginHandler like this:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def post(self):
    self.get()

# or this
post = get
```

Comment: So how will this aid in changing get method to POST? Can I add handle requests for POST?

Comment: I don't actully know what you are trying to do. But I know that with the correct handler and correct URL, POST is definitely working.

Comment: I just want to allow post method for all my forms, I have some idea of what you're suggesting `def post(self):` But I have no idea of what to put after that.

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon If you want LoginHandler to be able to handle POST, you should change LoginHandler instead. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I want but i don't know how to code it.

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon Well...if you want to do it simply, just call the get(self) method in auth.py where LoginHandler is located. Check out my edited answer for the code.

Comment: Hey it worked, is it possible for me to do the same thing but get post working for index.html as well?

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon  What is exactly `get post working for index.html`? If it's the `/login`, you already did that using the code above.

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon By the way, you can't actually use `/index.html` to get `/` or use `/` to get `/index.html`, because of tornado's handler setting.

Comment: After the user logs in, they are sent to /room/x.  On each of those rooms, I've made a form where the user can submit something, how can I make the POST method work in this form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69543/discussion-between-skyline75489-and-kingalfredchameleon).

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon Then you need to modify the MainHandler for that.

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon Or you could create a new Handler

Comment: So modifying the mainhandler seems a bit more feasible, would I just add def post..... (basically the same code in your answer)?