# Passing large amounts of data from one page to another without POST?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, apache

I'm using a web server framework which works with only GET requests, at the moment I'm trying to pass a large amount of data, that is the text content in a textarea which comes from user input, into another page which echoes the user's input.

I've attempted Querystrings but I end up receiving the error "Requested URL too long".

Any suggestions as to what method I should use?

Comment: a framework that works with only GET requests is a pretty bad framework

Comment: PUT and POST are the typical approaches. Any reasons why you don't use them?

Comment: `GET` requests are limited in size. `POST` on the other hand can handle arbitrary amounts of data.

Comment: You could make some experiments with memcachd.

Comment: @arkascha — memcached is usually used to save the server from CPU or disk IO intensive operations. How would it help with having too much data to fit in a GET request?

Comment: My original question which made reference to my framework  was this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951644/tornado-post-method-not-found but no one could answer it.

Comment: The only possible way of solving this is by changing the method on your Tornado framework, I've seen your question  and I don't think anyone here will be able to give you a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you can only send data encoded in GET requests, then you will have to break up the request and send it in multiple parts.

You could either use Ajax or store the entire set of data in localStorage and fetch each chunk in turn as the page reloads.

One approach would be to make a request to an end point that allocates you a unique ID. Then send a series of requests in the form: `?id=XXX&page=1&data=...` before closing it with `?id=XXX&total_pages=27` at which point you assemble the different pieces on the server.

**This way lies madness**. It would be much better to add POST support to your framework.

Comment: I agree, especially with the last point. Do you think you could help with my original question on adding POST to support my framework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951644/tornado-post-method-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Try using Javascript Cookies. 
you can store the textarea value there and then read it in another page (or wherever you want).

Here's a tutorial
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp